Can changing Gradient Descent step size/learing rate from constant 1/L to Armijo or exact line search change the convergence rate?
If instead of the classical $1/L$ constant step size we have adaptive step sizes chosen with exact line search or Armijo (let's say) can this alter the Big-O complexity of the convergence rate?
In Searching for Optimal Per Coordinate Step Sizes with Multidimensional Backtracking the authors note that
"... even an exact line-search cannot improve the convergence
rate beyond what is achievable with a fixed step-size".
But this is for strongly convex functions - would the same be true in general non-convex case?

I might be grossly wrong, but I think that line search will increase the averaged rate of convergence. What will not change is the order of convergence, as the search direction of the gradient descent is almost always first-order wrong. Just try out the usual test case of a slim ellipsis, that is, a quadratic function with a matrix with a small and a large eigenvalue. $L$ will be the large eigenvalue, for search directions dominated by the eigenvector of the small eigenvalue line search will be substantially better than the 1/L factor.

Summary
As this question involves lower-bounds, it would require a more explicit formulation to answer generally. However, if you are referring to the standard oracle complexity framework used by Carmon et al. [1], and the standard assumptions of non-convex optimization, the answer is no. Note however, that this framework does to the best of my knowledge not include exact line search as it only gives local oracle access to the function.
Proof
The standard assumptions of non-convex optimization are:

The objective function is lower bounded: $F(x_1) - \inf_{x \in \mathbb R^d} F(x) \leq \Delta < \infty$.
The objective function is $L$-smooth: $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R^d \colon \Vert \nabla F(x) - \nabla F(y)\Vert \leq L \Vert x-y\Vert$.

By [1, Theorem 1] any algorithm that only has access to an oracle that returns zeroth and first order information requires at least $\Omega\left(\Delta L \varepsilon^{-2}\right)$ oracle calls to reach an $\varepsilon$-stationary point under these assumptions.
On the other hand the convergence guarantee of $\texttt{GD}$ with stepsize $\eta = \frac 1 L $ under these assumptions is
$$
\min_{t \in [T]} \Vert \nabla F(x_t) \Vert^2
\leq \frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T \Vert\nabla F(x_t)\Vert^2 
\leq \frac{\Delta L}{T}
$$
which implies an oracle complexity of $\mathcal O\left(\Delta L \varepsilon^{-2}\right)$ to reach an $\varepsilon$-stationary point.
Since these are matching, no algorithm that only uses zeroth and first order information can improve upon the oracle complexity of $\texttt{GD}$ with stepsize $\eta = \frac 1 L$ under these assumptions.

[1] Carmon, Y., Duchi, J.C., Hinder, O. et al. Lower bounds for finding stationary points I. Math. Program. 184, 71–120 (2020). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10107-019-01406-y

+1. Could you complete this with analysis for the Convex and the Strongly Convex case?

Things get a lot more complicated when one considers the (strongly) convex setting, as $\texttt{GD}$ does not achieve the first-order oracle complexity bound lower-bound in this setting. There has been a lot of recent research on this question using Performance Estimation Problems (PEP), in particular [2] includes a discussion on exact line-search. Sadly I am not very familiar with this line of research, I would however be interested in it myself.
[2] Taylor, A.B., 2017. Convex interpolation and performance estimation of first-order methods for convex optimization

Oh, I thought it was a solved problem and the fastest rates were known. Also thought that it is known that accelerated method achieve the highest achievable rate (Asymptotically). Interesting paper is The Fastest Known Globally Convergent First Order Method for Minimizing Strongly Convex Functions (Slides).

Yes, optimal oracle complexities are known and achieved by accelerated algorithms. These algorithms can however not be written as $\texttt{GD}$ with certain stepsizes, which was the original question to my understanding. For $\texttt{GD}$ with non-constant stepsizes recent works still improve the theory, see e.g. here.

I get the question as: For 1st order methods, given an adaptive step size, can the convergence rates be improved compared to constant step size? The OP talked on non convex, I asked for convex and strongly convex.

Appreciate your knowledge sharing. I do remember when I saw the Twitt of Ben Grimmer on taking long steps occasionally.
